# tcsh equivalent to bash's unset-variable aware '+' parameter substitution command?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, tcsh

When setting up paths in bash, I've been taught to use the [plus sign command](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMALTV) alternate value parameter substitution, to be robust to situations where the variable isn't already set.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/new/libray/path/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

This way the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is set to `/new/libray/path/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set, and just `/new/libray/path/` if it is not. (This is less important in the common path variables, but is a great help when working with program-specific path variables, like `$PYTHONPATH`.)

Unfortunately, I'm in a situation where I need to use tcsh instead of bash. Is there a good alternative to this bash construct in tcsh? That is, what is the best way to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to 
`/new/libray/path/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set, and to set it to just `/new/libray/path/` (without raising an error) if it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature. You'll have to test for the existence of the variable with an `if`:

```
if ( $?LD_LIBRARY_PATH ) then
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /new/libray/path/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /new/libray/path/
endif
```